# Почему изображение не анимируется в отличии от div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, анимация

```
<body>
<button id="button1">Нажать</button>
<br/> <img class="el" width="280" height="256" src="images/4.jpg">
<style>
    div {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #abc;
        left: 50px;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>
<div class="el"></div>
<script>
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $('.el').animate({
            bottom: '+=50px'
        }, 'slow')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Судя по коду, причина в том, что вы `div` присвоили `position: absolute;`, а не `.el`

Answer (score 0):

Поместите изображение внутрь div'a

```js
$('#button1').click(function () {
        $('.el').animate({
            bottom: '+=50px'
        }, 'slow')
    });
```

```css
div {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #abc;
        left: 50px;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<button id="button1">Нажать</button>
<div class="el">
  <img width="280" height="256" src="images/4.jpg">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#button1').click(function () {
  $('.el').animate({
    bottom: '+=50px'
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
/* Для Блока */
div.el {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #abc;
  left: 50px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
}
/* Для картинки */
img.el {
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button1">Нажать</button>
<br/> <img class="el" width="280" height="256" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/517406a65cad01c8c9a54ebb3a8b35cd?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
<div class="el"></div>
```